# Returning all the friends connected with a user

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was looking to see where I can improve on my query to get all the friends of a user. I was originally thinking of inserting 2 rows per add in order to run

```
SELECT * 
FROM friends
WHERE friends.requesterId={id};
```

Problem with this approach is the result of N^(N-1) since I'll have double the insertion. I was hoping to use a join or union but I might not understand it correctly. I have tried doing

```
SELECT * 
FROM "friends"
WHERE "requesterId"=2
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM "friends"
WHERE "receiverId"=2
```

This results in a problem of itself where one row becomes

| id | requesterId | receiverId | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2 | 4 | "Accepted" |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | "Accepted" |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | "Accepted" |

As we can see, if we were to depend on receiverId alone to list our friends, it'll result in us also saying we friended ourselves.

Any idea or advice on what I should consider?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't include the column where you already know what the value will be (the 'self' value).

```
SELECT id, receiverId AS friendID, 1 AS is_my_request, status
  FROM friends
 WHERE requesterId = 2

UNION ALL

SELECT id, requesterId AS friendID, 0 AS is_my_request, status
  FROM friends
 WHERE receiverId = 2
```

Note, I also changed the column name, to just being the `friendID`, and added a column to say if "I" made the rquest or not.

I also changed `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.  That's because `UNION` uses compute resources to check for and remove duplicates.  In this case that would be asted resource.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. Quick question, what does 1 and 0 represent? I will be giving you the right answer as well :) Also thank you for explaining the difference between UNION and UNION ALL

Comment: 1 : `id = 2` made the request.  0 : the other person make the request.